# How to change the index of YUI tabview - YII

Tags: jquery, yii, yui, tabview

I'm trying to reassign the index of selected YUI TabView in jquery `tabview.on('SelectionChange')` , I could not get any idea to reassign the tabindex in jquery, please look into the below code.

```
<script
    src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/yui-min.js"></script>


<body class="yui3-skin-sam"> <!-- You need this skin class -->
<div id="demo">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#foo">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bar">bar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#baz">baz</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <div id="foo">foo content</div>
        <div id="bar">bar content</div>
        <div id="baz">baz content</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
YUI().use('tabview', function(Y) {
    var tabview = new Y.TabView({
        srcNode: '#demo'
    });

    tabview.render();
    tabview.on('selectionChange', function (e) {

     alert(tabview.indexOf(e.newVal)); // How to change its index here

});
}); 
</script>
    <?php echo CHtml::textField('tab', '', array('id' => 'tab_id')); ?>
</body>
```

Please can anyone guide me to set the new index of selected tab.

Comment: Do you mean get index of selected tab?

Comment: I need to change the index of all tabs in jquery